# primefaces schedule crazy lazy load parameters

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2

I'm using the primefaces schedule component to create a schedule where the timezone is fixed to UTC. So, event times should appear in UTC no matter where the client browser happens to be, and no matter where the server is -- independent of any local time zone.
To do that I set both the timezone and clientTimezone attributes to "UTC".

That all appears to work fine in the displayed view.

I'm also using the lazy loading method where it fetches events from the server when the view changes. So, when I click on the "day" mode, I would expect that the fetch would retrieve events for the selected day, either from midnight to midnight, or maybe minTime to maxTime.

```
loadEvents now  =2017-11-16 03:29:26 +0000 2017-11-16 03:29:26 +0000
loadEvents start=2017-11-15 04:00:00 +0000 2017-11-15 04:00:00 +0000
loadEvents end  =2017-11-16 04:00:00 +0000 2017-11-16 04:00:00 +0000
```

Here, I opened schedule for default date (today), selected day view, and printed out the start/stop time parameters to the loadEvents call.
This shows that current day is nov 16, but the fetch starts at 04:00 the day before, and cuts off at 04:00. Local TZ is UTC-8 (Los Angeles), but I can't see how adding or subtracting that offset arrives at these values.

Is that how it's supposed to work?

I'm using primefaces 6.1.8 under java8/tomcat, jsf2.2

Comment: Check the jquery-fullcalendar source. Might be an off-set in there

Comment: Haven't reviewed the js client in much detail yet, but I did take a look at the implementation of the ScheduleRenderer component in the pf library. 
The encodeScript method (line 144) sends the initial day selection as a string formatted as yyyy-MM-dd with no TZ, and using default (local) TZ in the formatter. If js side interprets that in specified TZ different from server TZ it's going to be wrong. i

Comment: JS sources in the pf distro are all obfuscated, so it's pretty hard to trace that. But I did clone a copy of fullcalendar at the 2.9.1 commit level, and in that code it appears to call a user-supplied fetcher with rangeStart, rangeEnd, and also passing the timezone. I believe that those time values are numbers rather than zoned strings. Presumably the fetcher is provided by pf, and I don't have readable source for that.

Comment: You have an elite release. All sources can with it in uncompressed format. Should not be too difficult to run them.

Comment: I can run it, but it's difficult to trace the obfuscated javascript. However, I can verify that the start/end values sent in the ajax request that implements the fetch is sending values that match what I'm seeing inside loadEvents in the bean. So, whatever inverted conversion is happening appears to be happening in the javascript. 
If my elite release includes uncompressed js sources, I don't see them.
Thanks for the help, by the way.

Comment: Also not in src/main/resources/META-INF/resources ?

Comment: Found the sources, and fixed a bug in my debug time formatter. Now I can see that the actual offset in the values coming back is exactly -8h, which is exactly my local TZ offset. 
I suspect that the error is in setupEventSource line 13365 where it gets the detault offset, which is then added to start and end parameters just before sending the ajax request.  Should probably use start.utcOffset() instead.

Comment: So it works now?

Comment: I don't know how I would test that fix. I'm only saying that I know there's a bug, and that looks like it might be it.
I can work around the bug in my system by sending the browser local tz to the server, and then re-offsetting the loadEvents times before using them.  
BTW, it's only incorrect if you set clientTimezone to anything but "local". I'm sure that's what most users use, and why nobody else noticed the bug.

Comment: The please file an issie PF github